# How do I make a many to many relationship in database?

Tags: sql

I want to make a fleet management program for the car in my organization, but in erd diagram I face problem I have two table

**Driver table** `Diver No, Name,Address, Car No`

**Car table** 
`Car No,Driver No`

I want to make design many to many relationship means one car can drive by many drivers and one driver can drive more cars.
My question how I represent this relation in the database and interface (meaning are I make a table to driver and table to car only in case that relation is many to many or what I do )

Comment: For future reference I'd avoid the word interface as it's a very specific thing in development - it confuses the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a DriverCar table which contains both DriverID and CarID and foreign keys to the appropriate tables.

Depending on your data access model you can either use a clustered PK or create a separate identity column.

Any other data (such as how long each driver has spent in each car) would be logged against this table.